# How to resolve angular build failure "Angular2-Notification" argument error in NotificationType class?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, visual-studio-code

These are my versions of node, npm and angular installed in my system:
[image]

but the issue is not resolved i have even tried changing the angular versions 7.0.5 to 7.0.7 in project. and in the system i have installed angular latest and tried but same issue, below is the issue i am getting

```
import { NotificationsService } from 'angular2-notifications';

export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private notificationsService: NotificationsService) {}

ngOnInit() {

this.notificationsService.create("Covering Letter", 'Covering Letter is required', 'error', 'yes');
this.notificationsService.create("Covering Letter", 'Covering Letter is required', 'success', 'yes');
this.notificationsService.create("Covering Letter", 'Covering Letter is required', 'warn', 'yes');

}

}
```

Below is the package.jason details

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.0.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.0.5",
    "@angular/common": "^7.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.0.5",
    "@angular/core": "^7.0.5",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.0.5",
    "@angular/http": "^7.0.5",
    "@angular/material": "^7.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.0.5",
    "@angular/router": "^7.0.5",
    "@kolkov/angular-editor": "^0.12.3",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "@reactivex/rxjs": "^5.5.11",
    "angular-datatables": "^6.0.0",
    "angular-material-fileupload": "0.0.11",
    "angular2-notifications": "^1.0.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.19",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.19",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.0-rc.4",
    "google-libphonenumber": "^3.2.2",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "ng-treetable": "^1.3.3",
    "ng2-carouselamos": "^3.2.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
    "ng2-simple-smooth-scroll": "^0.3.0",
    "ngx-dropzone-wrapper": "^6.1.0",
    "ngx-mat-select-search": "^1.4.2",
    "ngx-slimscroll": "^5.2.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.1",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.10.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "^0.1002.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.0.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "^7.0.5",
    "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.12",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.4",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "ng-packagr": "^3.0.0-rc.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tsickle": "^0.32.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.3",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~3.2.4"
  }
```

the Error is:

```
src/app/test1/test1/test1.component.ts(46,69): error TS2345: Argument of type '"error"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NotificationType'.
src/app/test1/test1/test1.component.ts(49,82): error TS2345: Argument of type '"success"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NotificationType'.
src/app/test1/test1/test1.component.ts(95,82): error TS2345: Argument of type '"warn"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NotificationType'.
```

Below is the notification service class

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { NotificationEvent } from '../interfaces/notification-event.type';
import { Notification } from '../interfaces/notification.type';
import { Icons } from '../interfaces/icons';
import { NotificationType } from '../enums/notification-type.enum';
export declare class NotificationsService {
    globalOptions: any;
    constructor(globalOptions: any);
    emitter: Subject<NotificationEvent>;
    icons: Icons;
    set(notification: Notification, to: boolean): Notification;
    success(title?: any, content?: any, override?: any): Notification;
    error(title?: any, content?: any, override?: any): Notification;
    alert(title?: any, content?: any, override?: any): Notification;
    info(title?: any, content?: any, override?: any): Notification;
    warn(title?: any, content?: any, override?: any): Notification;
    bare(title?: any, content?: any, override?: any): Notification;
    create(title?: any, content?: any, type?: NotificationType, override?: any): Notification;
    html(html: any, type?: NotificationType, override?: any, icon?: string): Notification;
    remove(id?: string): void;
}
```

And the NotificationType is

```
export declare enum NotificationType {
    Success = "success",
    Error = "error",
    Alert = "alert",
    Info = "info",
    Warn = "warn",
    Bare = "bare"
}
```

Comment: You are passing 'error' of type string. But you need to pass third parameter of type NotificationType.

Comment: NotificationType is an Enum; its from the Lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update angular2-notifications to latest version.
Please check this link - https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-notifications/v/9.0.0

```
create(title: any, content: any = '', type: string = 'success', override?: any, context?: any)
```

If you see above code type parameter is of type string. Also check this below documentation - https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-notifications/v/9.0.0#creating-notifications

Comment: So this means i need to replace as 'warn' to NotificationType.Warn 
`this.notificationsService.create("Covering Letter", 'Covering Letter is required', NotificationType.Warn, 'yes');`

Comment: No, you need to update angular2-notifications to latest version after that you can use `NotificationType.Warn`